# Ajax POST returning render_template in Flask?

Tags: python, ajax, flask, jinja2

I have some form which should be sent to the server (as POST request), store a certain object in the DB and return back a new template with some data.

In normal conditions, this would just work fine, but the issue here is that from the form data a quite complex JSON object is created, and that is what should be stored in the database. The JSON is successfully retrieved but the template redirection isn't working:

```
@app.route('/entry', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def entry():
    if request.method == 'GET':
        #Do some stuff
        return render_template('entry.html')

    elif request.method == 'POST':
        #Store the JSON object received and return back a new template with some data
        data = request.json
        db.store(data)
        #Retrieve some other data
        other_data = ...
        return render_template('diary.html', data=other_data)
```

I would like to know what is the general approach in these situations (I'm pretty new to Python and Flask itself). To me it looks like this shouldn't be a problem but I can't find an elegant solution to this.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I include the JS related code pretty simplified:

entry.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var json = {
                'foo': 1,
                'bar': 2
            }
            $.ajax('entry', {
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    console.log(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

diary.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var data = {{ data|safe }}
        console.log(data);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

The behaviour noticed is that jinja template isn't returned, but the HTML page content in the success callback from the POST ajax request:

[image: Chrome dev tools shot]

I'd like to render the new template with the retrieved data after this POST request (done via Ajax).

Comment: "The JSON is successfully retrieved but the template redirection isn't working:" Do you see an error?

Comment: We'll need to see your javascript or JQuery for how you handle the response.

Comment: @warunsl Actually no error is thrown, but Flask simply returns HTML code, which is not interpretated by the browser.

Comment: I'm struggling with the same question, and below answers don't seem to work. Have you found an elegant solution?

Comment: @JennaKwon unfortunately not

Comment: @jarandaf how about making multiple Ajax calls ?

Answer (score 1):

**this will help you**

```
!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function(){
                var json = {
                    'foo': 1,
                    'bar': 2
                }
                $.ajax('entry', {
                    url='type url here',
                    type: 'POST',
                    dataType='json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(json),
                    contentType: 'application/json',
                    success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                        console.log(errorThrown);
                    }
                });
            });
        </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

**at back end   receive data like this way**

```
variable=request.get_json()
```

now variable is dict

I think this will help you

Comment: How does this help redirect to another html upon completion?

Answer (score 0):

give this code a try:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(function(){
            var json = {
                'foo': 1,
                'bar': 2
            }
            $.ajax('entry', {
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(json),
                contentType: 'application/json',
                success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR){
                    document.write(data);
                },
                error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown){
                    console.log(errorThrown);
                }
            });
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_html.asp

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I would require to pass some data to the other template, i.e. I don't want to update any DOM element from the current page, but render a new one with the retrieved data (a redirect would be fine if it accepts to pass data through).

Comment: did you try document.write(data); to get the jinja2 html on the page after the POST?

Comment: Does not document.write just append HTML content to the current page? That isn't what I want to achieve.

Comment: Perhaps you could clear the html on the page and replace it with the diary.html. I can look into that if you want.  Why don't you just redirect on success in the js to get the diary.html?